# Postfix qmgr[]: warning: connect to transport private/test: No such file or directory and mail transport unavailable

Tags: postfix

I added to Postfix the following options:

master.cf:

```
test unix - - n - - smtp
```

main.cf:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps
test_destination_rate_delay = 5s
test_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

transport_maps:

```
domain.com  test:
domain2.com test:[smtp-server.com]:587
```

After postmap and restart postfix I got that information in logs:

```
qmgr[]: warning: connect to transport private/test: No such file or directory
error[]: ..... status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

In this path: /var/spool/postfix/private I dont see a file: test

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If your service did not start, postfix would have mentioned so in the logs. Check the logs around the time you restarted the server. (also: smtp clients are commonly chrooted - `y` in 4th column, you have `n` - did you mean to do that / is that different from your default `smtp` line?)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. After reboot everything has repaired.
Missing file "test" from /var/spool/postfix/private has been created. But reset all services related to mail did not work only after fully reboot machine it worked.